# is Better to send 1 big packet over a socket than sending several small ones? JAVA

Tags: java, sockets, server

Im making a server/client program that sends 2 classes and 2 ints over a socket from the client to the server and back again from the server to the client (and so on). this takes relatively long time and this process is inside of a game loop, and its making things slow. My question is: what's the faster way to send those things?

- pack up all those things (every time i need) and then send that big packet to the server and back again (and then decompress the data).
- send those things one by one and back again. this will save the time it takes to pack up all those things (i guess).
- Or there is no difference at all between this approaches?

what is your opinion guys? any other way of speeding things up in this kind of processes?

Edit1: im working with TCP.

Comment: Your question is about packets, not packages. Don't misuse standard terminology.

Comment: TCP or UDP? This is very important, as they both work differently..

Comment: Check http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/96945/what-is-better-lots-of-small-tcp-packets-or-one-long-one the answer explains it pretty well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say go for the one packet option.  The cost to put in the buffer to send multiple items is relatively low vs. the trips up and down the network stack to get the blocks of data onto the wire.  making things go as a block will tend to get the IP windowing and such tuned to the larger blocks so they will tend to flow quicker than having to get multiple packets routed through the network.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that when you're using TCP (the network transport protocol used by http, https, ftp, rsync, etc.), the data that is being sent by the application is treated as an ordered byte stream, not as individual messages - in other words, the data is treated as a train of bytes, not as "chunks" or "blocks" of data.

Depending on the TCP stack implementation and on its configuration (e.g. TCP_NODELAY or TCP_CORK on Linux distros), small data segments received by the kernel might be buffered until one MSS of data can be sent (typically 1460 bytes), or the data might be sent right away, regardless of the application's efforts to control network packet size.

In any event, it really depends on what you mean by "better".  Are you trying to optimize for responsiveness or scalability?

Answer (score -1):

The choice between the options you listed depends on the use and the type of the application you are developing (texting, sending statistics data..). In general, it's highly recommended in a such case to use synchronous threading and yes sending few data on a network increase undoubtedly the speed of transferring BUT this will "generate" more coding on the server side because you'll be needing methods that serialize (since you're using class objects )and reorder the data before manipulating it.

Comment: [If Im undeestanding your issue right] : Thread = process, if you are using one thread (in other words: if you're not using threads--> only one thread "main thread" is used to do all the job). Using multiple threads both in client or server side may help to "distribute tasks" eventually increase the speed of transferring and executing. There's plenty of thread synchronization tutorials on the internet, here's a complete exemple http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074318/java-concurrency/java-101--understanding-java-threads--part-2--thread-synchronization.html

Comment: Everything written here about threading here is irrelevant to the question that was asked, and the rest of it is basically wrong. It is always better to send fewer larger transmissions in TCP.